# Are there proper definitions for these phrase components?

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering if there are proper definitions when referring to these components of a phrase, examples below:

- "The **'Fire'** **'Escape'**"
- "An **'Emergency'** **'Room'**"
- "These **'Warning'** **'Stickers'**"
- "The **'Cup'** **'Holder'**"

I'm referring to the 2 words marked up in each phrase, and what they would be individually defined as.

Thank you!

Comment: Chicken soup. They are nouns, of course. The first is an adjunct that adds to the meaning of the second. Read up on "noun adjunct." Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you sir! Exactly what I needed